# Animating UITabBarController navigation

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, core-animation

I'm currently having an issue with iOS development regarding animation. I'm currently using the following code to make a "slide animation" for switching tab bar items after a gesturerecognizer fires.

```
-(void)slideToTab:(int)controllerIndex
{
    if(controllerIndex >= 0 && controllerIndex < [self.tabBarController.viewControllers count])
    {
        // Get the views.
        UIView * fromView = self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.view;
        UIView * toView = [[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:controllerIndex] view];

        // Get the size of the view area.
        CGRect viewSize = fromView.frame;
        BOOL scrollRight = controllerIndex > self.tabBarController.selectedIndex;

        // Add the to view to the tab bar view.
        [fromView.superview addSubview:toView];

        // Position it off screen.
        toView.frame = CGRectMake((scrollRight ? 320 : -320), viewSize.origin.y, 320, viewSize.size.height);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                         animations: ^{

                             // Animate the views on and off the screen. This will appear to slide.
                             fromView.frame =CGRectMake((scrollRight ? -320 : 320), viewSize.origin.y, 320, viewSize.size.height);
                             toView.frame =CGRectMake(0, viewSize.origin.y, 320, viewSize.size.height);
                         }

                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             if(finished)
                             {
                              // Remove the old view from the tabbar view.
                              [fromView removeFromSuperview];
                              self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = controllerIndex;
                             }
                         }];
    }
}
```

For the tab bar items on the tab bar this code works fine, but whenever I hit the first tab that's located on the "More" section of the tab bar, the animation stops working and the finished boolean in the completion block returns false. 
Is there a reason why this could happen in the "More" section of a tab bar and what would be a possible solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing custom tab bar transitions isn't officially supported under iOS 6, but under iOS 7 you can have your tab bar's delegate implement

```
-tabBarController:animationControllerForTransitionFromViewController:toViewController:
```

and return an object that implements

```
-transitionDuration and -animateTransition:
```

that will execute the transition.